# Can't install DeepSpeech on Raspberry Pi 4 Virtualbox

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian, debian-based, mozilla-deepspeech

Tried to install DeepSpeech via `pip3 install deepspeech` and got this:

```
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://www.piwheels.org/simple
Collecting deepspeech
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement deepspeech (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for deepspeech
```

Output of `cat /etc/os-release`:

```
PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)"
NAME="Debian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="10"
VERSION="10 (buster)"
VERSION_CODENAME=buster
ID=debian
...
```

Output of `uname -a`:

```
Linux raspberry 4.19.0-8-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.19.98-1 (2020-01-26) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Any idea? Also tried it with specific deepspeech versions, I get the same error.